# how to acquire the component position at specific time from motion study result?

Tags: c#, solidworks, solidworksapi

I am facing the problem to get position of a component at specific time from motion study result. There is only `GetCMPosition` method in the [API](https://help.solidworks.com/2021/english/api/swmotionstudyapi/SolidWorks.Interop.swmotionstudy%7ESolidWorks.Interop.swmotionstudy.IMotionStudyResults_members.html?verRedirect=1), which is the center of mass, not the origin point of the component. So do I need to calculate it by myself? But I do think there is a better way to acquire it.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours I found a solution myself... post pseudo code here and hope it could help someone.

```
public static ActionResult ExtractAnimation(this MotionStudy ms)
{
    if (!ms.Activate())
        return ActionResult.Error("activate motion study failed!");
    double duration = ms.GetDuration(); // in seconds

    if (duration <= 0) return ActionResult.Error("error message");

    for (double currentTime = 0; currentTime < duration; currentTime += AnimationStepSize)
    {
        ms.SetTime(currentTime);
        MethodUsingTransform(component.Transform2, currentTime);
    }

    ms.SetTime(duration);
    MethodUsingTransform(component.Transform2, duration);

    ms.Stop();
    return ActionResult.Success();
}
```